# jQuery .trigger not executing second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

I have some radio buttons on a page like this:

```
<div id="testdiv">
    <input type="radio" name="testing" class="my_rad" value="Radio 1" />
    <input type="radio" name="testing" class="my_rad" value="Radio 2" />
    <input type="radio" name="testing" class="my_rad" value="Radio 3" />
    <input type="radio" name="testing" class="my_rad" value="Radio 4" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_check" value="Checkbox 1" class="my_other_element" />
</div>
```

I have a custom `onChange` event attached to the checkbox with class my_other_element, what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
$('#testdiv').on('change', '.my_other_element', function(){
    $(this).trigger('onChange');
});

$('#testdiv').on('change', '.my_rad', function(event){
    // do stuff
    $('.my_other_element').trigger('onChange');
    // do more stuff
});

$('#testdiv').on('onChange', '.my_other_element', function(){
    alert('THIS IS EXECUTED');
});
```

So when I select a radio button, I do some stuff then I trigger the onChange event of `my_other_element`, then I do some more stuff. The problem I have is that my trigger to the onChange event of my_other_element is executed the first time I select a radio button. But If I select another radio button again (a second, third, or whatever time), my trigger is not even executed. I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do here. Any idea why my trigger gets executed the first time but not the second, third, fourth, time?

Thank you

Comment: its `$(this).trigger('change');` in jquery. and i haven't seen the onchange event anywhere in the codes you given

Comment: you never actually bound anything to the onChange event, unless you left that part out.

Answer (score 0):

The event is `change`, so no need to fire `onchange`

```
 $(this).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onChange` in jQuery use `change`

```
$(this).trigger('change');
```

**Also please check your logic:** as you are binding the onChange event on `div` and p `tag` also you are creating a [**recursion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) on this functions